# Get value when sending a key

Tags: java, guava

I have this code for Guava Multimap:

```
String key = "first-key";
Multimap<String, String> map = ArrayListMultimap.create();

map.put(key, "firstValue");
map.put(key, "secondValue");
map.put(key, "thirdValue");

map.putAll("sec-key", Sets.newHashSet("am", "are", "is"));

for (String name : map.keySet()) {  
    System.out.println("key: " + name); 
}
```

I want to query this structure for values.

For example: How I can send value `are` and get the result `is`?

Answer (score 1):

Both `are` and `is` are **values** mapped to the **key** `sec-key`. There's no straightforward way of looking up a value by a different value using just a multimap. The mutlimap is meant to map **keys** to **values**. Not values to values.

You could of course do something like this, but this is very inefficient - this code requires us to iterate over the entire map:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entries()){
    if (entry.getValue().equals("are")) {
        System.out.println(map.get(entry.getKey())); //will print the values mapped to the same key as `are`.

        break;
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to use a second map, one in which `are` will be the key, and `is` will be the value (or one of the values in case of a `Mutlimap`). If you make sure to keep both mutlimaps in sync, you'll be able to lookup quickly in both directions.

Comment: But I have one main key and 3 values. How to use 2 maps?

Comment: One map for Key -> Value. A second one for Value -> Key or a mutlimap of Value -> Other values

Comment: Can you show me working example please? I'm not aware how to search values into the maps.

Comment: Take a look at the apache commons collections Bidirectional Maps (BiDiMap)

Comment: ok, but I need to store 4 values. BiDiMap can store only key-value pairs?

Comment: No. You wanted an example of a bidirectional map. That's an example of a bidirectional map that maps keys to values and values to keys

Comment: can you propose some solution how to store 4 values like Multimap and get diff rent values?

Comment: You can write a bidirectional multimap that uses two multimaps to map keys to values and values to other values. Or a multimap, plus a regular map for mapping keys to values and values to keys.

Comment: wow. Can you please show me example how to query into this structure?

Comment: Take a look at the apache commons BiDiMap. It uses two maps for a similar purpose.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement a query by sending a key, please?

Comment: I'm not going to implement it, but I can explain the idea of how it can work. You use a Mutlimap K->V and a Map V -> K. Given a value, you use the Map to get the key, then look it up in the multimap to find the other values. Alternatively, you could use two Multimaps - one K->V, the other V->V. Given a value, you use the second multimap to find all other values for the same key. You then take both your maps and put them in a single class with a "put", "get" and "getByValue" method.

Answer (score 0):

> For example: How I can send value are and get the result is?

"are" is not a key mapped to a value "is". You can only get a value by passing a key to a map.